# Suggested tag synonym for wolfram and mathematica

Tags: discussion

There are two not very used tags, wolfram and mathematica. There are two posts under the wolfram tag and 3 posts under mathematica. These two topics seem fairly similar so should a synonym be created?

Also if this is not deemed appropriate could the wolfram tag be renamed wolfram-engine? Since the two questions tagged wolfram are both about the wolfram-engine, opposed to wolfram in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does seems a bit silly.  I thought they made sound cards too but probably that's *Wolfson* ;)

So I merged the tags and left a synonym [wolfram](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram) -> [mathematica](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematica) behind.  However, it seems that Mathematica makes more sense as a subcategory of Wolfram-engine than vice versa, so I then created [wolfram-engine](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-engine) and mapped [mathematica](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematica) to that, with the blurb:

> Wolfram-engine implements the Wolfram language and powers applications such as Mathematica. Use this tag for questions about any of the above.

Which is a bit flippant, but I qualified that in the wiki:

> Note that Mathematica has [it's own Stack Exchange site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/), and questions about general use belong there. This tag is expressly for issues with installation of Wolfram products on the Raspberry Pi, and other questions unique to the platform.

Thanks again for taking the time to point things like this out.

Comment: May I suggest expanding the scope of the tag to include uses of Mathematica that are unique to the RPi?  E.g. accessing and using the GPIO pins from Mathematica.

Comment: @DaddytheRunner Done -- I added "and other questions unique to the platform".